# calling a different classes function via a form php

Tags: php, html

We are toying about with the Open Source Flamer app. We noticed that they are able to call a function in a separate class located in a different PHP file via a form POST request. Here is an example of how they do it:

```
<div id="upldate_location_service" class="div_service">
        <form action="process.php/upDetails" method="post">
            <h3>Update location :</h3>
            <div class="form_row">
                <div class="form_label">Session Token *: </div>
                <div class="form_field"><input type="text" name="ent_sess_token" />name= "ent_sess_token"</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
                <div class="form_label">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="form_field"><input type="submit" name="ent_submit" value="Submit" /></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The function they are trying to access is UpdateLocation in the file Process.php. We have tried to recreate this process but it wont work. We can echo outside of our class, but for some reason we cant access or run any content in our process.php function.

Here is a copy of our process document:

```
class LegitAPI Extends API{
    public function upDetails($args)
    {      
        echo "Hello World";  
    }
}
```

Theoretically, when submitting the form on the index page, it should load process.php and then the method upDetails in the LegitAPI Class and display hello world. However, a blank page is instead being displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post `process.php` ?

Comment: It's a massive document... I can link the original Index.php and process.php on pastebin

Comment: well, it does seems to be the point of failure... since the post will send the data to `process.php` and from there it's not routing correctly.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JzRxjAyn (process) and http://pastebin.com/8h5pqz6J (index). Our versions are pretty much similar to above, just with a little cod removed in process to shorten the stack post

Comment: my superficial impression is that process.php/upDetails is not a valid path so I suspect there is some rewriting going on.

Comment: We have a function inside process called upDetails, and we are trying to call it from the form using action:process.php/upDetails

Comment: I couldn't find any `upDetails` in process

Comment: They are the original documents.. i will upload our versions for you to peruse: http://pastebin.com/mstrLvfz(index) http://pastebin.com/3AhapPkb (process)